# @nestjsx/crud with TypeORM and Postgres: Cannot destructure property 'parsed' of 'req' as it is null

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I'm trying to set up the basic API endpoint as described here: https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#getting-started

I have managed to get swagger to generate the page with my API endpoints, but when I try to run e.g. http://localhost:3000/app-user/1098 I get the following error:

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot destructure property 'parsed' of 'req' as it is null.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'parsed' of 'req' as it is null.
    at AppUserService.getMany (C:\tmp\crud-demo\node_modules\@nestjsx\crud-typeorm\src\typeorm-crud.service.ts:99:13)
    at AppUserController.getManyBase (C:\tmp\crud-demo\node_modules\@nestjsx\crud\src\crud\crud-routes.factory.ts:215:27)
    at C:\tmp\crud-demo\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29
```

I'm using the latest libs:

```
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",   
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjsx/crud": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@nestjsx/crud-request": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@nestjsx/crud-typeorm": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.17"
```

Comment: Heads up, that package is old and unmaintained. I'd be surprised if someone answered why it's doing what it is on the newer versions of Nest